# Capture Following Nodes Until Specific Node

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have data like this:

```
<h4>Test1</h4>
<p>test</p>
<div>test</div>
<p>test</p>
<h4>Test2</h4>
<p>test</p>
<div>test</div>
<p>test</p>
<h4>Test3</h4>
<p>test</p>
<div>test</div>
<p>test</p>
```

I'm trying to capture all sibling nodes of an H4 until I reach another H4.

I'm currently using:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//h4”>

<xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::*[generate-id(preceding-sibling::h4[1]) = generate-id(current())]"/>

</xsl:for-each>
```

This works but it captures the last h4 tag. I want to exclude that h4 tag. Output looks like this currently:

```
<p>test</p>
<div>test</div>
<p>test</p>
<h4>Test2</h4>
```

Is there a way to not capture the h4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `following-sibling::*[not(self::h4)]` instead of `following-sibling::*`.

Comment: I should have noted that there could be several sibling tags after the sample I gave. If I use following-sibling::*[not(self::h4)] it grabs the rest of the entire page.

Comment: It is not clear which elements you want to process (your select all `h4` elements in `//h4`) nor it is clear in which way you want to structure the output (you simply copy stuff without wrapping it) but at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS2B6B you can see that my suggestion does help to "capture all sibling nodes of an H4 until I reach another H4".

Comment: Your fiddle suggestion works for me. I was confused by the wording in your initial response but I think it's correct. Thanks.